# Implementing JWT authentication in Asp.net WebApi using Microsoft System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, restful-authentication

My question precisely is that "**how is the token validating information managed on WebApi side ?**"

i.e

A) Is there a unique secret key for each User?

B) If yes where are these stored ?

C) Some one said the key is generated fresh every session :O ??

**I would specify how I think this is to be done or can be done.**

1) App sends the username and password to login Api(Part of WebApi).

2) Api validates credentials from Database and creates a JWT.

3) A standard header is created say header = {'type':'JWT', 'alg':'HMAC'}.

4) Then claims/payload section is created and a unique identifier for that user is embedded into it.

5) Then (header.claims) is Base64URLEncoded and fed into a method which takes this encoded info and secret key as parameter and signs it using HMAC algorithm(say).

6) Now the header, claims, signature(obtained in previous step) are concatenated with periods and we get a JWT.

7) This JWT is sent back to the App.

8) During next request the App sends back this JWT to the WebApi while trying to access a resource.

9) The WebApi checks the JWT and decodes back header, claims from it.

10) The WebApi obtains the Unique user identifier from claims and checks if this user exists in the Database.

11) If user is found it gets the secret key associated with the user which is also stored in the Database against the user. (May be just a GUID generated at the time of registration)

12) It checks whether the token is expired or not. This info is available in claims/payload as 'exp' Date time or whatever.

13) Assuming that the token has not yet expired, The WebApi takes the header plus claims/payload and again generates the JWT same way it did the previous time using secret key.

14) The JWT so created is matched against the JWT sent by the App. If both match(signatures) then the token is correct and un-tempered and indeed issued by the WebApi to this user.

15) The WebApi sets the claim identity and allows the access to the resource.

Now instead of every time looking for the user identifier in the Database, The WebApi may also just maintain a static array of users as they login keeping their secret keys too. So it can just get the information from this array. As user logs out the user is removed from the static array as well.(The array management is not what I want to get into now)

This is just my way of thinking about implementing it.

**I want to know how much have I deviated from the way it's done otherwise?** I DO NOT want to create a separate authorization server. I want the WebApi to manage this itself in a simple but of course secure way. I will use Microsoft JwtSecurityTokenHandler for .Net 4.5 for creating, validating JWT's.

Answer (score 0):

Your  question is very generic in this topic and it takes many pages of answer. Please take a look on: [JSON Web Token in ASP.NET Web API 2 using Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)
it will answers many of your questions